# Apply lambda on a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, pandas-apply

I have the below data frame

```
ipdb> csv_data
  country_edited  sale_edited  date_edited  transformation_edited
0          India       403171     21091956                      1
1         Bhutan       394096     21091956                      2
2          Nepal       361372     21091956                      3
3         madhya       355883     21091956                      4
4          sudan       262949     21091956                      5
```

and below is my code

```
transfactor_count = 5.6
csv_data["transformation_edited"] = csv_data["transformation_edited"].apply(lambda x: x * transfactor_count)
```

But the above code  was giving me an error

```
*** NameError: global name 'transfactor_count' is not defined
```

How to solve this ?

### Actual code

```
for foreign_key in data_mapping_record.csvdatabasecolumnmapping_set.all():
    data_type = foreign_key.data_type
    trans_factor = foreign_key.tranformation_factor
    if data_type == "Decimal":
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
        csv_data[foreign_key.table_column_name] = csv_data[foreign_key.table_column_name].apply(lambda x: x * trans_factor )
    elif data_type in ["Date", "Datetime"]:
        csv_data[foreign_key.table_column_name] = csv_data[foreign_key.table_column_name].apply( lambda d: datetime.strptime(d, dates[date]) )
```

Comment: For me it works, but why dont use `csv_data["transformation_edited"] = csv_data["transformation_edited"] * transfactor_count` or `csv_data["transformation_edited"] = csv_data["transformation_edited"].mul(transfactor_count)` ?

Comment: Or there is some another code which can cause error?

Comment: basically i was using django and i am gonna get transfactor_count from database

Comment: Is possible use `csv_data["transformation_edited"].mul(foreign_key.tranformation_factor)` ?

Comment: like `csv_data[foreign_key.table_column_name] = csv_data[foreign_key.table_column_name].mul(foreign_key.tranformat‌​ion_factor)`

Comment: *** TypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21')

Comment: It seems more complicated, how works csv_data[foreign_key.table_column_name] = csv_data[foreign_key.table_column_name]* foreign_key.tranformation_factor) ?

Comment: yeah it worked i need to convert `foreign_key.tranformation_factor` to `int(foreign_key.tranformation_factor)`, but the problem is why can't i access the variables just before i declared ? like for example i have declared `dates = {
        'dd/mm/yy': "%d/%m/%Y",
        'mm/dd/yy': "%m/%d/%Y",
    }` as  a dictionary, but when i tried to access like `csv_data[foreign_key.table_column_name].apply( lambda d: datetime.datetime.strptime(d, dates[foreign_key.date_format]) )` it says `*** NameError: global name 'dates' is not defined` ?

Comment: any idea why we are getting global name error ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133966/discussion-between-shiva-krishna-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error already says, the lambda function can't find the **global** variable.
You can try make it global by:

```
global transfactor_count
transfactor_count = 5.6
csv_data["transformation_edited"] = csv_data["transformation_edited"].apply(lambda x: x * transfactor_count)
```

But as jezrael pointed out:

```
csv_data["transformation_edited"] = csv_data["transformation_edited"] * transfactor_count
```

is much more elegant.

you might have to change the datatype to float before:

```
csv_data["transformation_edited"] = csv_data["transformation_edited"].astype(float) * transfactor_count
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use lambda on dataframe as below:

```
transfactor_count = 5.6;
csv_data['transformation_edited']=map(lambda x: x * transfactor_count, csv_data['transformation_edited'])
```